# how can i fetch all images src into array with file get content

Tags: php

How can I fetch all images src into array with `file_get_content()`, with `preg_match` or whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. You should use classes like [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to do so. DOMDocument has the [getElementsByTagName](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) method that can be used to retrieve all the *img* tag from the document you want to parse.

Here's an example that will echo the list of the images in the document :

```
<?php
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML(file_get_contents('yourfilehere.html'));
    $lst = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');

    for ($i=0; $i<$lst->length; $i++) {
        $image = $lst->item($i);
        echo $image->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->value, '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more reliable and simpler to use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or [SimpleHTMLparser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (more elaborate). But for basic *extraction* purposes, and just searching for src= attributes, this is overkill and an regular expression **is** in fact *sufficient*:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src\s*=[\'\"\s]?([^<\'\"]+)/ims', file_get_contents($url), $uu);
```

Note that it will yield relative path names, mostly not URLs. So needs postprocessing, whereas phpQuery IIRC has a shortcut for normalizing them.

Comment: Regex **isn't** sufficient this will parse things you might not want such as image in comments.

Comment: @HoLyVieR, you'd have a real world example? Nobodys talking about parsing.